# Does mean=mode imply a symmetric distribution?

Tags: distributions, mean, skewness, mode, symmetry

I know this question has been asked with the case mean=median, but I did not find anything related to mean=mode.

If the mode equals the mean, can I always conclude this is a symmetric distribution? Will I be forced to know also the median for this manner?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125084

Comment: Many binomial distributions are skewed but have mean = mode.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Mean = mode doesn't imply symmetry.

Even if mean = median = mode you still don't necessarily have symmetry.

And in anticipation of the potential followup -- even if mean=median=mode *and the third central moment is zero* (so moment-skewness is 0), you *still* don't necessarily have symmetry.

... but there was a followup to that one. NickT asked in comments if having all odd moments zero was enough to require symmetry. The answer to that is also no. [See the discussion at the end.$^\dagger$]

Those various things are all implied by symmetry (assuming the relevant moments are finite) but the implication doesn't go the other way - in spite of many an elementary text clearly saying otherwise about one or more of them.

Counterexamples are pretty trivial to construct.

Consider the following discrete distribution:

```
  x     -4    0    1    5
P(X=x)  0.2  0.4  0.3  0.1
```

It has mean, median, mode and third central moment (and hence moment-skewness) all 0 but it is asymmetric.

[image: Asymmetric discrete pmf with mean=median=mode and moments skewness 0]

This sort of example can be done with a purely continuous distribution as well. For example, here's a density with the same properties:

[image: Asymmetric density with mean, median and mode 0 and zero moment-skewness]

This is a mixture of symmetric triangular densities (each with range 2) with means at 
-6, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 5 and mixture weights 0.08, 0.08, 0.12, 0.08, 0.28, 0.08, 0.08, 0.20 respectively. The fact that I just made this now -- having never seen it before -- suggests how simple these cases are to construct.

[I chose triangular mixture components in order that the mode would be visually unambiguous -- a smoother distribution could have been used.]

---

Here's an additional discrete example to address Hong Ooi's questions about how far from symmetry these conditions allow you to get. This is by no means a limiting case, it's just illustrating that it's simple to make a less symmetric looking example:

```
   x    -2    0    1    6
P(X=x) 0.175 0.5  0.32 0.005
```

[image: plot of the above p.m.f.]

The spike at 0 can be made relatively higher or lower without changing the conditions; similarly the point out to the right can be placed further away (with a reduction in probability) without changing the relative heights at 1 and -2 by much (i.e. their relative probability will stay close to the 2:1 ratio as you move the rightmost element about).

---

More detail on the response to NickT's question

$\dagger$ The all-odd-moments zero case is addressed in a number of questions on site. There's an example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125084/does-mean-median-imply-that-a-unimodal-distribution-is-symmetric/125104#125104) (see the plot) based on the details [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical/84220#84220) (see toward the end of the answer). That is a continuous unimodal asymmetric density with all odd moments 0 and mean=median=mode. The median is 0 by the 50-50 mixture construction, the mode is 0 by inspection -- all members of the family on the real half-line from which the example is constructed have a density that's monotonic decreasing from a finite value at the origin, and the mean is zero because all odd moments are 0.

Comment: I think the moral of the story is: symmetry is a strong property and can't be deduced from a few typical summary values of the distribution.

Comment: An interesting question might be how "close" to symmetry can you get with these properties. Looking at your discrete example, it's kind-of sort-of symmetric with a hump in the middle.

Comment: @HongOoi I expect you mean to ask how far you can get rather than how close (since obviously you can make it perfectly symmetric any time you want). You can make it a good deal more asymmetric than my example -- it was just a convenient case.

Comment: @HongOoi I have added another example.

Comment: If all the (odd?) moments beyond the variance are 0, would that only happen iff there's a symmetric distribution?

Comment: @NickT  No, you can have mean=median=mode *and every odd moment 0* but still have asymmetry. I was considering putting that in as well, after I added the bit about the third moment.. Looks like I should have. I have linked to some other posts that deal with the "all odd moments" part and discuss why you can still get mean=median=mode as well.

Comment: @Glen_b: Would it be a duplicate to ask a separate question about the *signs* of the skewness coefficient $sk=E(X-\mu)^3$? E.g., if $sk>0$, does that imply that the distribution is skewed to the left - assuming a proper definition for such a situation exists in the first place?

Comment: @Christoph That is indeed the difficulty -- outside a specified measure of skewness, how are we to decide if a distribution is skewed to the left? (In some cases, it's obvious enough, but in many cases it isn't.

Comment: However, if we choose another measure of skewness as our standard (say mean-median skewness) then we can certainly have that and third-moment skewness being of opposite sign.

Answer (score 19):

Try this set of numbers:
\begin{align}
X &= \{2,3,5,5,10\}  \\[10pt]
{\rm mean}(X) &= 5  \\
{\rm median}(X) &= 5  \\
{\rm mode}(X) &= 5
\end{align}

[image: Histogram]

I wouldn't call that distribution symmetrical.

Answer (score 10):

**No.**

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $p(X = -2) = \tfrac{1}{6}$, $p(X = 0) = \tfrac{1}{2}$, and $p(X = 1) = \tfrac{1}{3}$. Obviously, $X$ is not symmetric, but its mean and mode are both 0.

Answer (score 5):

To repeat an answer I gave [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941786/example-of-a-distribution-that-is-not-symmetric-but-has-a-skewness-of-zero/1942908), but fits here too:

$$\mathbb{P}(X=n) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       0.03 &  n=-3 \\
       0.04 &  n=-2 \\
       0.25 &  n=-1 \\
       0.40 &  n=0 \\
       0.15 &  n=1 \\
       0.12 &  n=2 \\
       0.01 &  n=3  
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

[image]

which not only has mean, median and mode all equal, but also has zero skewness.  Many other versions are possible.