# Alternate definitions of risk in decision theory?

Tags: loss-functions, decision-theory

In decision theory, given a family of distributions $(P_{\theta})_{\theta \in \Theta}$ on the data space $\mathcal{X}$, the risk $R_L(\theta, \delta)$ of an estimator $\delta$ for a given loss function $L(\theta, d)$ is given by
$$R_L(\theta, \delta) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} L(\theta, \delta(x)) \, dP_{\theta}(x)$$
I have only seen cases where the loss function $L$ is nonnegative, making the risk function $R_L$ effectively an $L^1$-norm. Just considering the $L^1$-norm of $L$ seems a bit restrictive.

For example if we wanted to talk about the tails of $L(\theta, \delta(X))$ when $X \sim P_{\theta}$, why not use for example an Orlicz norm, $\|\cdot\|_{\psi}$? Then we could look for an estimator that minimizes
$$R^{\psi}_L(\theta, \delta) = \|L(\theta, \delta(X))\|_{\psi}$$
In the case of $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ or a similar norm, this would imply we are looking for an estimator such that $L(\theta, \delta(X))$ has (at least for a minimum assumed decay rate $\exp(-t)$, $\exp(-t^2)$ or similar) the fastest decaying tails.

I haven't been able to find anything, but I am guessing that the choice of loss function can account for this, at least to within an arbitrarily small error?

Comment: By definition, norms cannot be negative.  Moreover, this formulation works for all valid loss functions, which also (by definition) cannot be negative.

Comment: @whuber What I am asking is if instead of the integral of $L$, which is the $L^1$-norm of $L$ since it is nonnegative, why not take for example $\psi_1$-norm of $L$.

Comment: The integral is the *expectation* of $L.$  That's the key.

Comment: Re the edit: I can't figure out what you might mean by "the tails of $L,$" because $L$ is not a probability distribution.  If you want to weight extreme values of $L$ differently then simply change $L$!

Comment: @whuber yeah that was abuse of language on my part. What I was attempting to say was that given the truth $\theta$, and $X \sim P_{\theta}$, instead of talking about the expectation of $L(\theta, \delta(X))$, we could get different information about $L(\theta, \delta(X))$, i.e. the decay of the tails via the $\psi_1$-norm of $L(\theta, \delta(X))$.

Comment: @whuber  Instead of minimizing the expectation, we could for example look to for an estimator that maximizes $\alpha$ such that the tails of $L(\theta, \delta(X))$ are sub $\exp(-x^{\alpha})$. We could phrase that optimization problem in terms of Orlicz norms.

Comment: But, again, unless you are contemplating a change that depends on the ordered pair $(\theta,\delta(X)),$ you can achieve whatever you want either by modifying $L$ or changing the distribution family.

Comment: @whuber Ah so you can account for that by changing the loss. I was kind of expecting that. But that is good to know. I was thinking maybe it was because you couldn't as easily make a Bayesian connection. However, if you need just modify the loss, then that is not a problem. I will think about how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @whuber, the risk is defined as expected loss. It is not the only criterion possible, and decision theory studies many of other alternatives for making decisions, but as discussed in [Why care so much about expected utility?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313290/why-care-so-much-about-expected-utility) we have have many good reasons to care about expected loss.