# Measures of Uncertainty in Higher Order Moments

Tags: variance, mean, skewness, moments, kurtosis

Suppose I have a sample of data and compute the mean. I am able to quantity uncertainty in this by computing the variance. I am wondering if known methods exist for evaluating the uncertainty associated with other moments. Specifically, if I compute the variance, skewness and kurtosis of a sample, is there some known formula to determine how uncertain each result is? Any help and associated references would be very helpful.

Comment: Skewness and kurtosis have analytical formulas for SE.

Comment: Do you have a reference that explains these?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245835/range-of-values-of-skewness-and-kurtosis-for-normal-distribution

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for